# why are Plurals for thousand, million and such unit are not used commonly, like in amount description?

Tags: word-usage, prefixes

why don't we say 2 thousands instead 2 thousand (just an example) in spite of it being more than a unit amount and neither is it an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 4):

*In line with a moderator's [note](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10647/142322) about posting partial answers, I'm submitting this answer as a test-balloon of sorts. It is a partial answer and something of a conjecture, but not a request for clarification.*

---

Let's consider a slightly fuller example: *two thousand years*. It's possible that *thousand* is singular because it (or more accurately, *two thousand*) acts as a premodifier of *years*, similar to the role of *train* in *two train stations*.

> - Nouns which act as premodifiers are singular, even when the head is plural
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/noun-phrases/noun-phrases-dependent-words)
> - Finally, when using plural nouns as premodifiers, they are often changed to the singular. Therefore, "the leg of the trousers" becomes "the trouser leg". "The lens of the binoculars" turns into "the binocular lens". Although this change is normal, it is not universal, e.g. "the race of arms" becomes "the arms race", where "arms" stays plural.
>   [- Scientific English as a Foreign Language](https://users.wpi.edu/%7Enab/sci_eng/98_Sep_4.html)

[Note](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404261/why-are-plurals-for-thousand-million-and-such-unit-are-not-used-commonly-like/404263?noredirect=1#comment963321_404263) that in the phrase *several thousand**s** of years* we use the plural, *thousands*. This is because here, *several thousands* is not a premodifier of *years*, and simply stands alone. *Several* therefore [agrees](http://www.englishplus.com/grammar/00000027.htm) with the plural *thousands*. If we remove *of*, the phrase reverts to using the unmarked 'thousand': *several thousand years*.

Comment: It's also interesting that "several thousands of years" is perfectly common, but "two thousands of years" is not. Can you shed any light on this in your answer?

Comment: @MetaEd Thanks for raising the issue; addressed now. I've linked to your comment (the word "Note") to indicate the source of the discussion about *several*. Let me know if more extensive attribution would be preferred / more appropriate.